# What is the best type of array/loop to use here?

Tags: php, html, arrays

Let's say I have a simple markup.

```
<div class="wrapper" id=" <?php echo $id; ?> ">
  <div class="title"> <?php echo $title; ?> </div>
  <div class="inner-text"> <?php echo $inner-text; ?> </div>
</div>
```

I have a long list of titles,id's and inner text's that need to be inserted where the variables are and this block of code will need to be repeated at least 50-100 times.(There is no set amount as of right now)
Each $id,$title and $inner-text will not be random.

Example:

car

car

this is a fast car

---

This is how they should be represented

$id = car

$title = car

$inner-text = this is a fast car

How can I assign each set of three peices of information to individual variables, then put them into a `<div>` and loop through them until there is no more left to loop from the list.

If you don't understand what I mean then think of while loop with an associative array from a mysql database

I wish to do the same thing but just without the database part

Comment: add sample data of $titles,$ids etc

Comment: What do you mean, how can I use arrays and loops? Just, ehm, use them. It's not that difficult.

Comment: Can you show us an example of you data? The one you are referring on `long list of titles,id's and inner text's`

Comment: This is opinion based, chose one: `foreach`, `while`, `for` [(php.net manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php)

Comment: Try not to use "best" in a question, because opinion based questions are off topic on SE, as opinions can vary, or it could lead to a chat discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array with arrays:

```
$array = array(

array('id' => 1,
        'title' => 'somename'),
        'innertext' => 'sometext'),

array('id' => 1,
        'title' => 'somename'),
        'innertext' => 'sometext')
);
```

Then you can easily look through it afterwards like

```
foreach($array as $row) {

    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $innertext = $row['innertext'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you retrieve your data with a query.

```
$query = "SELECT id, title, inner_text FROM table";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query); //Be sure to establish the mysqli instance in your header or configuration file.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    echo '<div class="wrapper" id="'. $row['id'] .'">';
        echo '<div class="title">'. $row['title']; .'</div>';
        echo '<div class="inner-text">'. $row['inner_text'] .'</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

This is one of the basic methods of generating html code with php. The other way is with a nested array with your prefilled data.

You could use an foreach loop on the array and generate it in the same fashion. I don't know if you have a prebuilt array but if you show it to me I can edit my answer and give an example.

Answer (score 0):

First you should put those variables in array. For example: $data = array ('id' => someid,
'title' => sometitle,.... and so on
)

Next you should make foreach loop as folows:

```
<?php foreach($data as $rows_of_data_array) : ?>

 <div class="wrapper" id=" <?=$rows_of_data_array['id']; ?> ">
   <div class="title"> <?=$rows_of_data_array['title']; ?> </div>
   <div class="inner-text"> <?=$rows_of_data_array['inner-text']; ?> </div>
 </div>

<?php endforeach?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one array of **objects** :

```
foreach($myArrayOfObjects as $object){
?>
<div class="wrapper" id="<?php echo $object->id; ?> ">
        <div class="title"><?php echo $object->title; ?> </div>
        <div class="inner-text"><?php echo $object->innerText; ?> </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

If you have one array of **arrays** (multidimensional array) :

```
foreach($myArrayOfcontentArrays as $contentArray){
?>
<div class="wrapper" id="<?php echo $contentArray['id']; ?> ">
        <div class="title"><?php echo $contentArray['title']; ?> </div>
        <div class="inner-text"><?php echo $contentArray['inner-text']; ?> </div>
</div>
<?php
}
```

If you have 3 **correctly indexed and same sized arrays** ($ids, $titles and $innerTexts) :

```
for ($i= 0; $i < count($ids), $i++){
?>
<div class="wrapper" id="<?php echo $ids[$i]; ?> ">
        <div class="title"><?php echo $titles[$i]; ?></div>
        <div class="inner-text"><?php echo $innerTexts[$i]; ?> </div>
</div>
<?php   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multi-dimensional array.

```
$array=array(
  array(0 =>'id', 1 =>'title', 2=>'inner-text'),
  array(0 =>'id1', 1 =>'title1', 2=>'inner-text1'),
  array(0 =>'id2', 1 =>'title2', 2=>'inner-text2')
);

$c=count($array); //the value of this is 3

for($i=0; $i<$c; $i++){
  foreach($array as $key => $value){
    echo $array[$i][$key]. "<br />";
  }
}
```